# NMI gateway integration in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, payment-gateway, nmi-payments

We are planning to integrate [NMI](https://www.nmi.com/)
payment gateway for payment process in our NodeJS project and we found the list of supported gateways in Node [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-payment-gateways) ,

Can anyone please help us to find out a node module for NMI gateway integration if its there?

Comment: NMI payment gateway uses Direct Post method(DPM) for payment gateway integration. See if any packages are available for the same.

Comment: I found a tutorial to develop DPM integration packages here http://www.authorize.net/support/DirectPost_guide.pdf

Comment: This might help: http://node-modules.com/search?q=payment&u=